# Predicting screen dimensions after orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framework

I am trying to figure out the screen size I will have in portrait and in landscape at the beginning of my app.

I can get the real display size using `Display.getRealSize()` and then calculate the navigation bar height in case there is one.

However, in devices with `600dp` or less the navigation bar can have different heights (depending on orientation) and may even move to the right in landscape mode.

My app would needs to know these parameters when it begins (the app is connected to a cloud server that receives these dimensions when it connects - so I really need to know these before the app starts doing things).

My current solution is this:

```
Resources res = Resources.getSystem();
id = res.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
int navigation_bar_height = res.getDimensionPixelSize(id);
```

Although this works, it is never a good practice to use android's internal resources.

Is there any other way of knowing the dimensions of the screen in a different orientation *BEFORE* you rotate the device?

Answer (score 0):

For getting dimensions of devices.try following code

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    final int height=dm.heightPixels;
    final int width=dm.widthPixels;
```

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. This gives the screen metrics, but I would like to take into account the navigation and status bar heights. These parameters may have different sizes in different orientations and I would like to know them before I rotate the device.

Comment: did you find a solution in the end?